# foldr in Haskell: confusion

Tags: haskell

I just have a question about the usage of foldr.

Say I want to use foldr in this way:

```
foldr (\x y -> (x + y)/2) 2 [4,5,6]
```

Is `y` in this case represents each element of the list?

---

In particular, let's unwrap this function.

we have (x = 2, y= 6) -> (2+6)/2 = 4.

**Next, do we have x=4, y = 5?**

I am asking a simplify version of what I really want to ask. Here, the content of x and y represents matter a lot because in my application, I have a function that takes 1st argument as type a, and second argument as type b. Thus, I do need to know whats going on under-the hood.

Answer (score 2):

> Say I want to use foldr in this way:
>
> ```
> foldr (\x y -> (x + y)/2) 2 [4,5,6]
> ```
>
> Is `y` in this case represents each element of the list?

One way of figuring it out is looking at the type of `foldr`:

```
GHCi> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

The structure being folded has type `t a` for some `Foldable t` (in your case, you have a list, and so `t` is `[]`), and its elements have type `a`. The result accumulated through the fold has type `b`. The binary function used for folding has type `a -> b -> b`, so the elements are passed as its first argument, and the accumulated value, as its second.

Another way of figuring out is by reading [the actual implementation of `foldr` for lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr) (I found this by looking for the [`Foldable` instance of lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable) and then following the source links). You might want to try that, to see how one picture corresponds to the other.

Answer (score 1):

`foldr f startingValue (x:xs)` expands to `f x (foldr f startingValue xs)`, and `foldr f startingValue []` expands to `startingValue` so in your case:

```
foldr (\x y -> (x + y)/2) 2 [4,5,6]
(\x y -> (x + y)/2) 4 (foldr (\x y -> (x + y)/2) 2 [5,6])
(\x y -> (x + y)/2) 4 ((\x y -> (x + y)/2) 5 (foldr (\x y -> (x + y)/2) 2 [6]))
(\x y -> (x + y)/2) 4 ((\x y -> (x + y)/2) 5 ((\x y -> (x + y)/2) 6 (foldr (\x y -> (x + y)/2) 2 [])))
(\x y -> (x + y)/2) 4 ((\x y -> (x + y)/2) 5 ((\x y -> (x + y)/2) 6 2))
(\x y -> (x + y)/2) 4 ((\x y -> (x + y)/2) 5 4)
(\x y -> (x + y)/2) 4 4.5
4.25
```

It might be easier to see with `f x y = (x + y)/2`:

```
foldr f 2 [4,5,6]
f 4 (foldr f 2 [5,6])
f 4 (f 5 (foldr f 2 [6]))
f 4 (f 5 (f 6 (foldr f 2 [])))
f 4 (f 5 (f 6 2))
f 4 (f 5 4)
f 4 4.5
4.25
```

If you understand how cons lists are constructed (using `:`), you can think of `foldr` as replacing all the `:` with the function you provide.